# Normality of the subgroup generated by odd order elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Q. I have a finite group $G$, and a subset $H$ given by $$H=\{h\in G~:~O(g)~\text{is odd}\},$$

My doubt: Can we say that $H$ form a normal subgroup of $G$ in the light of order preserving property of conjugate isomorphism?

But I have to ensure $H$ is a subgroup, If not, what about the normality of the subgroup generated by $H$?

Comment: Let $\Pi$ be any set of primes. Consider the subgroup $K$ of $G$ generated by the elements whose order is a $\Pi$-number. Then $K$ is a *characteristic*, hence normal subgroup of $G$. This is simply because automorphisms preserve orders. (Actually, $K$ is fully invariant, that is, it is sent into itself by all endomorphisms of $G$ .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being asked about the subgroup generated by the elements of odd order (the set you propose is a not a subgroup in general, try with $S_4$).

Since the inverse of an element of odd order has odd order, the subgroup you want consists of the elements of the form
$$
a_1a_2\dots a_n
$$
where each $a_i$ has odd order.

A conjugate of this element would be
$$
g(a_1a_2\dots a_n)g^{-1}=(ga_1g^{-1})(ga_2g^{-1})\dots(ga_ng^{-1})
$$
and each $ga_ig^{-1}$ has odd order because conjugation by $g$ is an automorphism of the group.